# Can't get field from json query

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm doing a select using sequelize, when I get the response, I'm triying to return a field but I'm getting undefined.

The function is:

```
async getSchemaName(id){
    if(id == 'public') return id
    //let schema = await Cliente.findByPk(id)
    let schema = await Cliente.findAll({
        attributes: ['schema_name'],
        where: {id: id}
    },{raw: true})
    console.log(`aqui esta el esquema ${JSON.stringify(schema)}`)
    console.log(`aqui esta el esquema ${schema.schema_name}`)
    console.log(`aqui esta el esquema ${JSON.stringify(schema.schema_name)}`)
    //if(schema)
        return schema[0].schema_name
    //else return null
}
```

And the console gives me this:

```
aqui esta el esquema [{"schema_name":"cbpo_davivienda_wiser"}]
aqui esta el esquema undefined
aqui esta el esquema undefined
```

Do you have any idea where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`schema` is an `Array`, you can access it like so:

```js
var schema = [{"schema_name":"cbpo_davivienda_wiser"}];
document.write(schema[0].schema_name)
```

Comment: I'm using this one and getting the same error "undefined".

Comment: @CarlosJaramillo if your object contains a valid property called `schema_name` in schema just like above you can see that it works flawlessly.

Comment: I was hopping that. When I do a console of the varibale "scheme" get this: "[{"schema_name":"cbpo_davivienda_wiser"}]". But when I console "schema[0].schema_name" I get "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Your api return an array :

```
schema.forEach(data => {
    console.log(data.schema_name)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you fast answer. 

I'm using the code that you suggest and just getting at console "undefined"

Comment: Using the "JSON.parse(schema)" get "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1". But when I console "schema" in this way "console.log(`${JSON.stringify(schema)}`)" i get this "[{"schema_name":"cbpo_davivienda_wiser"}]"

Comment: so you should not need parse()... please try console.log(typeof schema)

Comment: or try data['schema_name'] within the loop